# Oracle database SELECT... FOR UPDATE with autocommit on

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm running this query against an Oracle database (11g). The connection has the default value for autocommit which is 'true'.

```
Connection con = driver.connect(url, properties);
String query = "SELECT EMPID, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE FOR UPDATE";

Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

[SELECT... FOR UPDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) states that it "lock the selected rows so that other users cannot lock or update the rows until you end your transaction." With autocommit on it should be immediately after the query is executed. But the lock is present till the connection is closed.

(I checked this by running query `select * FROM DBA_DML_LOCKS WHERE NAME = 'EMPLOYEE';` on sqlplus.)

Is this a bug or can somebody please explain why?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: P.s. The query works as expected when transactions are manually managed with autocommit turned off

Comment: Why do you use 'FOR UPDATE' when you don't update anything?

Comment: I do update! and use `resultSet.updateRow()` but the lock is kept till the connection is closed. which is problematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html):

> the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed, right after it is executed

Another [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10590/keyprog.htm#JSQLJ225):

> Enabling auto-commit may be more convenient, but gives you less control. For example, you have no option to roll back changes. In addition, some SQLJ or JDBC features are incompatible with auto-commit mode. For example, you must disable the auto-commit flag for update batching or SELECT FOR UPDATE syntax to work properly.

So for this query type you should use manual commit

Comment: the lock is present even after `resultSet.updateRow()` is executed. Sorry there was an error in my test case and I updated the question

Comment: The locks aren't released when `resultSet.cancelRowUpdates()` are executed or when the resultSet is closed either

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually implementing a connection pool thus I have no idea what queries would run. So I guess it should be user's responsibility to manage transactions or auto commit.

Answer (score 1):

I found this documentation.

[FOR UPDATE clause](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj31783.html) where it says: *The use of the FOR UPDATE clause is not mandatory to obtain an updatable JDBC ResultSet. As long as the statement used to generate the JDBC ResultSet meets the requirements for updatable cursor, it is sufficient for the JDBC Statement that generates the JDBC ResultSet to have concurrency mode ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE for the ResultSet to be updatable.*

And this one: [Requirements for updatable cursors and updatable ResultSets](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html#rrefsqlj41360__sqlj15384)

I assume you can skip the `FOR UPDATE` clause in your case.

Comment: My actual requirement is to find out why it's not working and not to run the specific query (as I have commented in the accepted answer). But thank you, this is something I didn't know before

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this FAQ.  AutoCommit should be turned OFF when using FOR UPDATE. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#30_06

Answer (score 0):

As [setAutoComit documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)) says:

> **The commit occurs when the statement completes**. The time when the
>   statement completes depends on the type of SQL Statement:
>    - For DML statements, such as Insert, Update or Delete, and DDL statements, the statement is complete as soon as it has finished
>   executing.
>    - **For Select statements, the statement is complete when the associated result set is closed.**
>    - For CallableStatement objects or for statements that return multiple results, the statement is complete when all of the associated
>   result sets have been closed, and all update counts and output
>   parameters have been retrieved.

So, in your case the lock will be present till either you close your ResultSet using [ResultSet.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) explicitly or the ResultSet is closed automatically (see [ResultSet.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) for more details).

And yes, you're right when you say that "it should be user's responsibility to manage transactions or auto commit".